# Python grok learning lists

Tags: python, grok

Hi I am working on a module for Grok learning and it gave me a problem to create a program that takes a **list** of students names and prints each name out individually and **alphabetically** as a class roll (each name capitalized).

```
#pseudo
# ask for students and store in 'students'
# split 'students', which is now a list
# sorts the list alphabetically
# print('Class roll')
# for i in students
# print i . capitalize

data = input('Students: ')
students = data.split()
students = students.sort()
print('Class Roll')
for i in students:
  print(i.capitalize())
```

and essentially it gives me this error message that I don't understand:

```
Students: a c b d
Class Roll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 13, in <module>
    for i in students:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comments are fine.

Comment: `students.sort()` does not return a new list. It works in place. Try `sorted` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `sort` on a list it sorts in place, rather than returning a sorted list. Try it without assignment, i.e.:

```py
data = input('Students: ')
students = data.split()
students.sort() # this line is changed
print('Class Roll')
for i in students:
  print(i.capitalize())
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your problem. Simply remove the equal sign since .sort() transforms the list itself.

```
data = input('Students: ')
students = data.split()
students.sort()
print('Class Roll')
for i in students:
  print(i.capitalize())
```